# VB.NET application to display data from an encrypted text file

Tags: vb.net, encryption

I am building an application which will read an encrypted text file.(this will be separated values), The application has to find the relevant rows and display it.

I'm planning to use Rijndael encryption , the goal is to obscure data from the user. However, the challenge is that if the file grows too large , it is impractical to read in memory and find the required data.
also reading the entire file into memory every time the data needs to be fetched will slow down the application.
Any suggestions on how to go about this?

Comment: A database comes to mind since at least it would be random access, or given that `this will be separated values` implies some known structure, you could serialize it.  The data would only be decrypted while in use.

Comment: What approach do i take ,assuming i want to read from an encrypted text file?  would binary serialization work? or is it better to stick with AES or other methods?